# Send image from C++ to Java using JNI

Tags: java, c++, bitmap, java-native-interface, byte

I'm trying to send an image from C++ to java using JNI. The image is a bitmap created in C++ where I cast the pixels using `GetDIBits` to a `char*`. When saving the image to a file using C++ there are no problems but when sending the pixels to Java the image is all blurry. The JavaDocs say I have to use `3BYTE_BGR` for BufferedImage but I feel there is something wrong in the compression

The C++ bitmap

Converting in Java to BufferedImage, the width and height are also received through jni

This is the result of the image

Comment: How should the image look like?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't have a qusetion.

Answer (score 1):

Given that bi.bitCount is 32, using `3BYTE_BGR` format for BufferedImage is incorrect:  it's assuming one pixel every three bytes, rather than one pixel every four bytes.  Instead, use `TYPE_INT_BGR`.  As we discussed in the comments, your DataBuffer will need to be a DataBufferInt, which you can accomplish by using ByteBuffer and IntBuffer, as in the following snippet:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_BGR);
IntBuffer intBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(img).asIntBuffer();
int[] imgInts = new int[img.length * Byte.SIZE / Integer.SIZE];
intBuffer.get(imgInts);
image.setData(Raster.createRaster(image.getSampleModel(), new DataBufferInt(imgInts, imgInts.length), new Point()));
```

Comment: I also thought about that but since I'm sending a byte[] the DataBuffer will give an exception because I can't cast a DataByteBuffer to a DataIntBuffer, and I do really want to send bytes instead of pixels ints

Comment: You can use java.nio.ByteBuffer.asIntBuffer to wrap and reinterpret 'img' as int[], then construct the DataIntBuffer that you need.

Comment: Updated my answer to demonstrate the use of ByteBuffer/IntBuffer.